# Distinct The return value in query inside for loop

Tags: php, mysql

i have this codes and the value is duplicating

> ```
>     output:
> Injury 
>   Injury  
>    Headache 
>    Headache
> ```
>
> i want result is
>     injury
>     Headache
>
> i try to distinct but nothing happens i show some picture to view all

```
  if(!empty($_POST['poscon'])) {
        foreach($_POST['poscon'] as $condition) {
            $condition=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$condition);
            $p=mysqli_query($link,"Select Distinct PossibleCondition 
                            FROM $tablename where Symptoms1='". $condition ."'");

            while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($p))
            {
                $spec=$r["PossibleCondition"];

                if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['poscon']) && in_array($spec,$_POST['poscon']))
                    $strIsChecked='checked="checked"';
                else
                    $strIsChecked=null;
                echo '<br><td><input type="checkbox" '.$strIsChecked.' title ="'.$spec.'" name="poscon[]"  onclick="javascript: submit()" value ="'.$spec.'"></td>';
```

Comment: Show us a sample from your PossibleCondition table. And what does `$_POST['poscon']` contain?

Comment: i edit my post i show some picture

Comment: Is "Disinct" in your query a typo (when copy pasting the code), or are you really missing a `t` ?

Comment: sorry my bad its typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select Distinct PossibleCondition` will return only different `PossibleCondition` values. However, you are looping `$_POST['poscon']` variable, and executing the query at each iteration.

Maybe -instead of looping- you could implode the `$_POST['poscon']` var (using commas) and use this as the where condition.

***Edit: code example***

```
if(!empty($_POST['poscon'])) {
    $condition=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,implode(",",$_POST['poscon']));
    $p=mysqli_query($link,"Select Distinct PossibleCondition 
                    FROM $tablename where Symptoms1 IN (". $condition .")");

    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($p))
    {
        // etc...
```

Comment: can you give me some outiline in codes ? sorry im new